# Attaching multiple plots to a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

The following bit of code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot(x='EstCurentMarketValueSqFt',
           y='MarketValueSqFt',
           data=sales,
           scatter_kws={'edgecolor': "black",
                        'linewidth': 1})
```

Generates the following picture:

[image]

However, I would like to additionally plot a pair of lines corresponding with the upper and lower bounds of the scatter. To do this I need to plot those lines on top of this existing plot.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sns.lmplot` does not immediately interface with `matplotlib` methods (at least, not in the way that I'm used to) because it's attached to a `sns.FacetGrid`.

After reading the API a bit more, `regplot` is recommended for this purpose. And that works:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
ax.set_xlim([0, 5000])
ax.set_ylim([0, 5000])
sns.regplot(x='EstCurentMarketValueSqFt',
           y='MarketValueSqFt',
           data=sales,
           scatter_kws={'edgecolor': "white",
                        'linewidth': 1},
          )
plt.plot([1, 5000], [1, 500])
plt.plot([1, 500], [1, 5000])
```

Gives:

[image]